# Why there are items with light blue background when browsing the homepage?

Tags: support

Why there are items with light blue background when browsing the homepage?

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are tagged with one of your favorite tags.  Looks like real analysis, in this case.

Comment: Related link: [What do “favorite tags” and “ignored tags” do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do) (taken from [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/favorites/info)).